# How to create a Stored Procedure to pick some columns from a table and create a XOR Cipher. Key value should be a date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to implement Data scrambling. I have a table with sensitive information and it has around 20 columns. I want only 5 of the columns like Name, Phone, email etc to be fetched from the table and use them in the XOR cipher for encrypting and keep in into a temp table. Could you please help me build a SP code for this? Key value should be a date

Comment: You are aware the XOR offers no security benefits and you may as well do ROT-13 (or the even more secure double-rot-13)?

Comment: Not sure about it. Can you please provide me detail about it? @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: [Why is writing your own encryption discouraged?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/43272)